# Como seria uma expressão regular para encontrar um atribulo html + valor do atributo?

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Estou querendo dar um find/replace em todos os atributos html "data-placeholder" e seus valores, da minha aplicação, através da busca do Visual Studio.

Para isso preciso montar uma expressão regular e colocá-la direto no find do Visual Studio, ativando a opção de expressões regulares.

Porém eu não sei quase nada sobre expressões regulares para conseguir criar uma do tipo.

Gostaria que a expressão regular me fizesse encontrar todos esses tipos de string:

```
data-placeholder="Texto 1"
data-placeholder="Texto 2"
data-placeholder="Texto com muitos caracteres"
data-placeholder=""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sou muito fera em regex rs, mas vou tentar ajudar:

```
(data-placeholder=")(\w+(\s+|\w+)\w+)"
```

Comment: Perfeito! Vou salvar para utilizar em outras situações!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazê-la assim :

```
data-placeholder="([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)"
```

Caso `_` não seja problema se diminui ela para :

```
data-placeholder="([\w ]*)"
```

#### Explicação

1. `data-placeholder="` busca literal, deve conter na string.
2. `(...)` Gera um grupo, match[1], pois match[0] é a proprio string.
3. `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` ou `[\w ]` sequencia de caracteres validos, não importando a ordem.
4. `*` quantificados, de zero a infinito, sempre capturando o máximo.
5. `"` busca literal, deve conter na string.

#### Obs

`\w = [a-zA-Z0-9_]`